# gatling - generate unique id of execution

Tags: gatling

I have simple scenario when I'm creating some object by sending `ElFileBody` based json with `post` method. I would like to pass to this file some unique id, that after execution of scenario all objects created with this test would have exactly te same id.

I was trying with

```
exec(session ->
  session.set("testExecutionId", java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString)
);
```

but this is executed a every run and each execution get own testExecutionId.
Can someone tell me is it posibble to do such thing, or maybe there is already something like this out of a box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first please use `feed` instead `exec` with `session.set` - this is a more correct way.
The nuance in your code is that the method `java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString` is called every time. We can solve this once by initializing the id via `val` variable.

```
val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString

val testExecutionFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("testExecutionId" -> uuid))
```

And then add to your scenario:

```
scenario(...)
    .feed(testExecutionFeeder)
    ...
```

Comment: So simple:) thank you!